# Does the order of a subordinate clause change meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning

When building a subordinate clauses we can put them at the end of a sentence, or at the beginning:

> Er lernt fleißig Deutsch, damit er sein Examen besteht.
> Damit er sein Examen besteht, lernt er fleißig Deutsch.
>
> Sprachen sind leicht zu lernen, sagte seine Mutter immer.
> Seine Mutter sagte immer, Sprachen sind leicht zu lernen.
>
> Wohin er auch blickte, überall standen Bücher.
> Überall standen Bücher, wohin er auch blickte.

Is there a (subtle) change of meaning when changing the order of clauses, or is this only a matter of style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part which comes first is the fact you want to emphasize. 
Note: Your 3rd line reads like a direct quote, so one might rather write:

> Seine Mutter sagte immer: "Sprachen sind leicht zu lernen".

As an alternative you could use an indirect quote:

> Seine Mutter sagte immer, Sprachen seien leicht zu lernen.